# Vis-a-vis maintenance and spare parts, what are a type certificate holder's "regulatory obligations"

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance

This conversation came up when the owner of an out-of-production airplane from a still-in-business manufacturer lost his gas cap. The manufacturer didn't have a spare part and refused to take an order for the production of said gas cap, effectively grounding the airplane permanently (if no salvage cap can be found, or if the owner cannot manufacture his own cap).

https://www.skytough.com/post/faa-type-certificate says "A type certificate can also be orphaned if the holder does not, or refuses to, comply with their regulatory obligations."

This leads me to wonder, what are the regulatory obligations and where are they spelled out? Certainly, the FAA cannot oblige a struggling manufacturer to start producing spare parts for older planes when it needs to focus on its survival. But there's also the very real situation that the owner is grounded and the factory won't help, not even with drawings.